# Make dynamic gridview header clickable

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, gridview

I have a dynamic gridview and the header row needs to have hyperlink. I can use the below piece of code for static grid.

**For Static Grid:**

```
<asp:boundfield datafield="ID" headertext="ID" headerstyle-wrap="false" Sortexpression="ID"/>
```

But how can I achieve for dynamic grid.

I am using the below piece of code to populate dynamic gridview headercell text. On top of this how can I make the header cell clickable.

**Code: To populate gridview header text dynamically from datatable**

```
if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)
            {
                string ID = ViewState["ID"].ToString();
                DataTable dtColumnNames = GetColumns(ID);
                string[] strColumns = dtColumnText.Rows.OfType<DataRow>().Select(k => k[1].ToString()).ToArray();
                for (int i = 0; i < strColumns.Length; i++)
                {
                    e.Row.Cells[i].Text = strColumns[i];
                }
            }
```

Answer (score -1):

An easy solution would be to just insert a link element.

```
if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)
            {
                string ID = ViewState["ID"].ToString();
                DataTable dtColumnNames = GetColumns(ID);
                string[] strColumns = dtColumnText.Rows.OfType<DataRow>().Select(k => k[1].ToString()).ToArray();
                for (int i = 0; i < strColumns.Length; i++)
                {
                    e.Row.Cells[i].Text = "<a href='myUrl'>" + strColumns[i] + "</a>";
                }
            }
```

or in newer C# syntax

```
$"<a href='myUrl'>{ strColumns[i] }</a>";
```

or to add a JavaScript call there are several ways

```
e.Row.Cells[i].Text = "<a href='javascript:myFunction()'>" + strColumns[i] + "</a>";
```

or

```
e.Row.Cells[i].Text = "<a href='#' onclick='myFunction()'>" + strColumns[i] + "</a>";
```

Comment: Actually I'm not passing any URL since the columns are dynamic. I need to have a click event fired when clicked on any header columns. Is this possible? I tried a lot and it didn't work.